# Read angle from a 360 degre meter

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, angle

I have a meter that I have managed to extract using openCV
[Image of the meter in different positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6686P.png) The white thing in the middle is a pointer that can go from 0-360.

My code:

```
void readAngleOfMeter(Mat image, int number)
{
    cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    inRange(image, Scalar(255, 255, 255), Scalar(255, 255, 255), image);

    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    HoughLines(tmp, lines, 1, CV_PI / 360, 30, 0, 0);

    if (lines.size() == 0) {
        cout << "No lines found" << endl;
        return;
    }

    float thetasum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        float theta = lines[i][1];
        thetasum += theta;
    }
    thetasum = thetasum / static_cast<int>(lines.size());
    cout << "Theta " << thetasum << endl;
}
```

My problem is now that I want to read the angle of the meter. So I thought about using the average angle of each line but the problem is that it doesn't work because a line can be interpreted in two ways (example 90 is the same as 270) and also when it goes from 360 to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should know the rough endpoint in the middle of the dial so if you get the extent of the line you should be able to get the angle in [0, 360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use Hough transform. Write a loop that iterates from 0 to 360 degress in 1 degree increments looking at pixels in a circle centred at the centre of the image. Remember the angle of the first white pixel and when you find the next black one going around the circle, take its angle and average with the starting angle.

You may want to blur a little first or dilate the meter needle to fill any gaps.

Experiment with the radius - a smaller radius will give you less resolution as the needle appears thicker there. A larger radius will give you more resolution but you risk missing the needle as it is thinner further from the centre.

Comment: I like this idea, gonna attempt it on Monday 

Comment: Cool - good luck! Let us know how you get on, or if it proves a mad, useless idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The Hough function will indeed leave an unrecoverable 180° indeterminacy.

You can compute the intersection, i.e. an estimate of the center point and check on what side of the ROI it lies (if necessary, sample along the bisector to find the direction of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, here's the code i used.

```
float radius = 50;
bool found = false;
float startv = 0;
float endv = 0;
for (float v = 0; v < 360; v++)
{
    int x = center.x + cos(v * CV_PI / 180.0) * radius;
    int y = center.y + sin(v * CV_PI / 180.0) * radius;
    Point p{x,y};

    if (!found && gray.at<uchar>(x, y) != 255) {
        startv = v;
        found = true;
    }
    if (found && gray.at<uchar>(x, y) == 255) {
        endv = v;
        break;
    }
}
```